# What's wrong in my code for show/hide function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML and javascript code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="common">
    Hi Welcome
</div>

<div>
    <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('customize');" >click here</a>
</div>

<div  id="customize">
    <form action="" method="post" id="MyForm">
        {%  form%}
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        if ($("#"+divId).show()) {
            $("#common").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#common").show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

If i click the link "Click here" one div id should be hide and another should be show and if i click it another time vice-versa process should be happened. i tried using this javascript but it's not worked properly

Comment: _one div...and another_ - which elements?

Comment: You're testing an item's visibility by looking at the jQuery 'show' method. That needs to change I think…

Comment: @BenPoole: ya by using jquery we can able to make show/hide function simultaneously?

Comment: You have to use change event instead of show ....

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `show()` and `hide()` rather than just `toggle()`

Comment: @iolo: I'm having two div functions when i submit a button one div should be hide and another should be show...when i clicked it again the process repeat it vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:visible` to check if the passed div is already visible. Try this:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    var $el = $("#" + divId);
    if ($el.is(":visible")) {
        $el.hide();
        $("#common").hide();
    }
    else {
        $el.show();
        $("#common").show();
    }
}
```

You should also change your code to use jQuery to attach you events instead of the clunky `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="link" data-rel="other-div">click here</a>
```

```javascript
$("#link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleDiv($(this).data("other-div"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    if ($("#"+divId).is(':visible')) {
        $("#common").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#common").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is always going to enter the `if`, never the `else`. You are evaluating the return value of [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), which is always a jQuery object which will always evaluate to true.

Check to see if the element is currently visible, using the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method and the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    if ($("#"+divId).is(":visible")){
        $("#common").hide();
    }
    else{
        $("#common").show();
    }
}
```

As a side note, why not move your event handler code out of the HTML and bind it with jQuery since you're already using it (the following assumes you give the link an ID of "yourLink"):

```
$("#yourLink").click(function() {
    //Event handler
});
```

Comment: And with this last deleted answer I say goodbye to answering javascript/html questions. There are too many of us here all the time and 6 answers within 6 minutes of submitting the question is way more than necessary. Back to the android boards.   -.-'

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the visibility of `$("#"+divId)` my applying the [jQuery .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method!

What you should be doing is testing the visibility with [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) like this:

```
if ($("#"+divId).is(":visible")) {...}
```

So you function should become:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    if ($("#"+divId).is(":visible")){
        $("#common").hide();
    }else{
        $("#common").show();
    }
}
```

---

**But**, if you just need to toggle the current display status of an element, you can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
  $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with no separate function.

```
<div id="common">
      Hi Welcome
</div>

<div>
<a onClick="$('#customize').toggle()" >click here</a>
</div>

<div  id="customize">
  <form action="" method="post" id="MyForm">
        Content
  </form>​​​​​​
```

Unobtrusive Example for bonus points:

```
<div id="common">
      Hi Welcome
</div>

<div>
<a data-linkedId="customize" >click here</a>
</div>

<div  id="customize">
  <form action="" method="post" id="MyForm">
        Content
  </form>​​​​​​

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(){
    $('a[data-linkedId]').on('click',function(){
        var divId = $(this).attr('data-linkedId');
        $('#'+divId).toggle();
    });
}
</script>
```